# Codeigniter using MYSQLI escape string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am currently updating a section of code that uses `mysql` currently the escape string is structured like this: `$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['product_name']));` and works fine.

My issue is when I change the above string to `$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, (trim($_POST['product_name'])));` and declare the following: `$database = $this->load->database();` above it I get the error that its NULL

How do I escape a string with CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter [user manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) wrote the following.

> Beyond simplicity, a major benefit to using the Active Record features is that it allows you >to create database independent applications, since the query syntax is generated by each >database adapter. It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped >automatically by the system.

You can use Input class in your controller.

```
$this->load->model('mymodel');
$something = $this->input->post('something');
$results = $this->mymodel->mymethod($something);
```

In your model

```
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use

$this->db->query("select ?",array("value"));

Where each ? In thee select is the variable you want escaped